# Como configurar autenticação HTTP com o JBoss?

Tags: lado-do-servidor, autenticação, jboss, autenticação-http

Gostaria de proteger meu site inteiro com usuário e senha, ví que é possível fazer isso usando autenticação HTTP, porém gostaria de saber como fazer isso no JBoss.

Comment: Um bom lugar para começar é http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch8.chapter.html

Comment: Se alguém sabe os passos para fazer isso favor postar aqui, pois a documentação é extensa demais e fica difícil saber o que daquilo tudo devo fazer. Quero apenas configurar 1 usuário e 1 senha para acesso. O mais simples possível.

Comment: Eu achei que seria alguma configuração simples de fazer, porém pelo jeito não é. Vou ler toda a documentação e tentarei resolver sozinho.

Comment: Rapaz, se o seu site está exposto na Web, provavelmente é uma boa vc colocar um Apache ou nginx na frente do JBoss. Não é considerado boa prática colocar o próprio JBoss servir sites (escutando em `0.0.0.0`)

Comment: Porque não é aconselhável utilizar só o JBoss? O JBoss é um servidor de aplicação, assim como o Tomcat ou o Apache, ou estou errado?

Comment: Então, tanto JBoss quanto Tomcat podem servir aplicações Java Web. Mas é uma boa prática de infra colocar um serviço HTTP como o Apache ou nginx na frente deles, pois assim não precisa expor o servidor de aplicações na Web -- eles só precisam conversar com o Apache/nginx. É comum aparecerem falhas de segurança nos servidores de aplicações, então escondê-los atrás do Apache dá uma estabilidade maior.

Comment: De qualquer forma, qual versão do JBoss você está usando?

Comment: Estou utilizando o JBoss EAP 6.1

Comment: Daniel T. Sobrosa, acredito que a resposta: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256625/6789) pode ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A API dos Servlets possibilita especificar a autenticação de recursos no web.xml. Veja um exemplo da [documentação do JBoss 6](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html_single/#Web_Content_Security_Constraints-_A_web.xml_descriptor_fragment_which_illustrates_the_use_of_the_security_constraint_and_related_elements.):

```xml
<web-app>
<!-- ... -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Content</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>AuthorizedUser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<!-- ... -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>The Restricted Zone</realm-name>
</login-config>
<!-- ... -->
<security-role>
    <description>The role required to access restricted content </description>
    <role-name>AuthorizedUser</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Como disse, isso faz parte da API do Java e inclusive é obrigatório para quem faz a certificação hoje conhecida como OCEJWCD.

Entretanto, o "cadastro" de usuários é realizado no Servidor de Aplicação (Container). Especificamente no JBoss, existe [esta documentação](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html_single/#sect-UsersRolesLoginModule) que ensina a colocar esses usuários em arquivos *properties*, mas também diz que é possível armazenar em banco de dados ou acessar um serviço LDAP.

Basicamente, o que você precisa fazer é especificar o módulo de autenticação desejado. No caso de arquivos *properties* é o `UsersRolesLoginModule`. Então você configura o módulo, como este exemplo:

```xml
<deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0"> 

   <!-- ejb3 test application-policy definition --> 
   <application-policy xmlns="urn:jboss:security-beans:1.0" name="ejb3-sampleapp"> 
      <authentication> 
         <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required"> 
            <module-option name="usersProperties">ejb3-sampleapp-users.properties</module-option> 
            <module-option name="rolesProperties">ejb3-sampleapp-roles.properties</module-option> 
         </login-module> 
      </authentication> 
   </application-policy> 

</deployment>
```

Finalmente, você cria os arquivos com os papéis (*roles*) e as senhas dos usuários (*users*):

```
username1=role1,role2,...
username1.RoleGroup1=role3,role4,...
username2=role1,role3,...
```

e:

```
username1=password1
username2=password2
```

Comment: Vale notar que o OP mencionou EAP 6, e não AS 6. É meio confuso, mas EAP 6 é baseado em AS 7 :-)

Comment: @jpkrohling Obrigado, não havia notado isso.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do utluiz está correta, especialmente porquê lida com JBoss AS 6. Para o JBoss AS 7 (incluindo JBoss EAP 6) e Wildfly, você deve criar um *realm* no `standalone.xml` e criar usuários dentro deste *realm*. O mais fácil é utilizar o script `add-user.sh`, que fica dentro do diretório `bin`. Isso é fácil para um ou outro usuário, e imagino que seja este o seu caso, mas se quiser expandir esta autenticação para centenas de usuários, então é recomendável que você leia mais sobre `JAAS`, o padrão que define autenticação e autorização para aplicações Java EE.

Vale a pena dar uma lida na [documentação sobre segurança do EAP 6.2](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Security_Guide/chap-Introduction_to_JAAS.html), para mais detalhes e opções.