# JAAS com Wildfly não funciona

Tags: java

Estou tendo problemas para realizar o jaas utilizando wildfly, apesar de conseguir cadastrar utilizando o DataSource normalmente,não consegui encontrar onde está o erro. Ao tentar acessar os recursos protegidos sempre é redirecionado para a tela de erro.

standalone.xml

```
    <security-domain name="login" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/RestDS"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select senha from Pessoa where email=?"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select roles_name,'Roles' from Pessoa_SystemRole as user_roles inner join Pessoa as p on p.id = user_roles.Pessoa_id where p.email = ?"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

persistence.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence version="2.1"    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Rest" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/RestDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

web.xml

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Seguranca</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
      <role-name>USER</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
  <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
  <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Comment: Poste o erro, que é importantíssimo pra ajudar a identifica-lo

Comment: Então Renan Carlos não gera nenhum erro no console. Ele parece estar funcionando normalmente porém sempre cai na página de erro configurada loginError.jsp.Mas obrigado pela dica mesmo assim.

Answer (score -1):

Quando temos que implementar o JAAS, e importante entendermos o mecanismo de como funciona a autenticação que utilizam as especificações da tecnologia Java EE:

> Serviços de segurança: o Serviço de Autenticação e Autorização Java (JAAS) permite que os serviços autentiquem e apliquem controles de acesso aos usuários. O Contrato do Provedor de Serviços de Autorização Java para Containers (JACC) define um contrato entre um servidor de aplicativos Java EE e um provedor de serviços de autorização, permitindo que os provedores de serviços de autorização personalizados sejam conectados a qualquer produto Java EE. A Interface de Provedor de Serviços de Autenticação Java para Recipientes (JASPIC) define uma interface padrão pela qual módulos de autenticação podem ser integrados com contêineres para que esses módulos possam estabelecer as identidades de autenticação usadas pelos contêineres.[[Gonçalves, Antonio -  2013](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DREFM0O), 10 p.]

Agora, na prática tenha em mente que no Java EE, os containeres são responsáveis por fornecer segurança de aplicativos. Um container basicamente provê dois tipos de segurança: declarativa e programática.

Pessoalmente, prefiro implementar segurança usando o tipo de segurança declarativa porque como as informações do descritor de implementação (web.xml; jboss-web.xml; standalone.xml; domain.xml) são contidos/definidos em um arquivo externo, ele pode ser alterado sem a necessidade de modificar o código-fonte. E isso é um benefício e reduz a manutenção e refatoramento dos código-fonte.

Para entender o tipo de segurança declarativa usando

[image: Tipo de segurança: declarativa]
Fonte: [[Michal Cmil et al -  2014](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/java-ee-7-development-wildfly), 309 p.]

Acredito que no seu caso, o próximo ajuste de configuração precisa ser executado no descritor da implantação da Web do JBoss, `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml`. Você precisa declarar o domínio de segurança aqui, que será usado para autenticar os usuários:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/login</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

E considere o seguinte:

> O formulário de login deve conter campos para inserir um nome de usuário e senha. Esses campos devem ser nomeados j_username e j_password, respectivamente. O formulário de autenticação deve postar esses valores no nome lógico j_security_check.
>
> Todos esses nomes que começam com j_ são padronizados pela especificação Java Servlet - precisamos apenas seguir a convenção para permitir que os mecanismos automáticos funcionem.[[Michal Cmil et al -  2014](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/java-ee-7-development-wildfly), 310 p.]

```
....
<form method="post" action="j_security_check" name="nameForm" >
....
```

<sub>**NOTA**: Desculpem pela parede de textos, mas infelizmente é necessário termos uma boa base teórica.</sub>

---

**Referência**: 
<sub>[Juneau, Josh -  2013], Apress, © 2013, **[Java EE 7 Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430244259)**: A problem-Solution Approach – Proven Solutions for Java Enterprise Edition 7 Developement</sub> 
<sub>[Gonçalves, Antonio -  2013], Apress, © 2013, **[Beginning Java EE 7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DREFM0O)** (Expert Voice in Java)</sub>
<sub>[JSR 196 - JASPIC], **[JSR 196 - JASPIC](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=196)**: JavaTM Authentication Service Provider Interface for Containers</sub>
<sub>[Anjana Mankale -  2013], Copyright © 2013 Packt Publishing, **[Spring Security 3.x Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/spring-security-3x-cookbook)**: Over 60 recipes to help you successfully safeguard your web applications with Spring Security.</sub>
<sub>[Michal Cmil et al -  2014], Copyright © 2014 Packt Publishing, **[Java EE 7 Development with WildFly](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/java-ee-7-development-wildfly)**: Leverage the power of the WildFly application server from JBoss to develop modern Java EE 7 applications.</sub>