# Autenticação e Segurança JAAS com multi modulos

Tags: java, java-ee, autenticação, glassfish, jaas

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação com a seguinte arquitetura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver o sistema vai ter vários módulos.

No Projeto Portal eu implementei o JAAS, e não estou conseguindo manter a autenticação quando entro em outro modulo dentro do sistema. Como posso fazer essa autenticação e manter o login em outra aplicação?

Comment: Como utilizar [essa configuração](https://emmanuelneri.com.br/2013/10/24/single-sign-on-no-jboss-7/) no glassfish?

Comment: Ítalo Gustavo Araújo, no contexto JAAS, acredito que a resposta: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256625/6789) pode ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Ítalo, isso depende de como está configurada sua aplicação, mas de formas gerais um **cookie com a sessão** do usuário é salva e checada de tempos em tempo para garantir o login antes do tempo que expire a sessão. Pelo que eu entendi do seu problema será necessário fazer o **compartilhamento de sessão** ou criar um outro cookie para a transição dessa informação, observando também que alguns padrões de segurança devem ser atendidos, como visto [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service) na parte de Form Authentication.

[FONTE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html)

Comment: Matheus, eu acredito que seja alguma configuração que não estou conseguindo implementar, em outro Fórum foi sugerido usar  Single Sign On (SSO). Eu encontrei a seguinte documentação: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4734/beacq/index.html

Mas não estou sabendo como aplicar no meu projeto!