# Caso o usuário acesse a home antes de efetuar login ele deve ser redirecionado para o index utilizando jsp

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee-7

Qual verificação devo fazer se o usuário acessar diretamente a página home.jsp sem ter feito o login? Ressaltando que não estou utilizando servlet para esta situação, apenas páginas jsp.

Código da página home.jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Bem vindo</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <%
            if ((session.getAttribute("login").equals(null)) || (session.getAttribute("login").equals(""))) {
        %>
        Você não esta logado. <a href="index.jsp">Por favor, entre com a sua conta.</a>
        <%
            } else {
        %>
        Seja bem vindo,
        <%=session.getAttribute("login")%>
        <center>
            <a href="http://localhost:8080/Atividade07/listUsers">Listar -
                Servlet</a><br> <a href="listar.jsp">Listar - JSP</a><br> <a
                href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>
        </center>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Código da página login.jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  action="checklogin.jsp" method="post">
            <center>
                <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="3">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">Login</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Login</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="login"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Senha</td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="senha"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                            <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">Ainda não esta cadastrado? <a href="register.jsp">Cadastra-se</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Elucidando ainda mais o contexto desta aplicação segue uma imagem da aplicação, que deve implementar a figura abaixo (Apenas falta a parte que está destacada).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vitor Oliveira, acredito que a resposta: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256625/6789) pode ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias formas de se fazer isso.

**UTILIZANDO FILTROS**

Você pode criar um filtro através da implementação da interface `javax.servlet.Filter`:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "MyFilter", urlPatterns = {"/principal.jsp"}, dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.INCLUDE})
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {


     HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

     if(req.getSession().getAttribute("login") == null) {
       response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
     } else {
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
     }

    }
}
```

*ENTENDENDO O FILTRO `MyFilter`*

Utilizamos a annotation `@WebFilter` que está presente na especificação *Servlet 3.1* para indicar que a classe criada será um filtro.

O atributo `urlPatterns` que é um `Array` de `String`, indica quais *URL's* esse filtro vai interceptar. Ou seja, o código do método `doFilter()` será executado antes mesmo da `request` chegar na *Servlet*, mas apenas quando a URL requisitada for `principal.jsp`.

A verificação feita dentro do método `doFilter` foi baseada no código que você postou na pergunta, mas poderia ser qualquer outra coisa. (Assume-se que depois do login, você utiliza o método `setAttribute` com a chave "login", salvando algum objeto Java indicando que o usuário está logado).

**UTILIZANDO JSP PURO**

*Essa forma é fortemente não recomendada. Use os filtros para uma melhor legibilidade e elegância do código.*

Também é possível utilizar apenas JSP com uma verificação do atributo "login" da sessão, no começo da página.
Caso dê negativo, você redireciona para login.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% if(request.getSession().getAttribute("login") == null) {
  resp.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
}
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Aqui continua seu HTML normalmente -->
<!-- ... -->
```

Acho que o código na JSP está bem claro e não necessita de maiores explicações.

Enfim, espero ter ajudado.
Qualquer dúvida, pode comentar na resposta. Abraços.

Comment: Olá amigo, bastante grato por ter elucidado este cenário. Então, não tinha conhecimentos sobre o uso do Filter, mas até então ficou claro a real funcionalidade do uso do Filter. O código da página home.jsp funcionou, apenas reescrivi e dei um clean no projeto antes de startar; mas é como você falou q não é fortemente recomendado. Pra galera que esta aprendendo a como fazer um login e um registro, em JSP, de um usuário segue o site que peguei como exemplo: http://www.javaknowledge.info/login-and-registration-example-in-jsp-with-session/